# Numpy using multidimensional array to index a 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-indexing

I do not understand the following code, i.e. the last part of it.

```
max = np.max(rel_coords, axis=0)
min = np.min(rel_coords, axis=0)
bins = [np.arange(low, high) for low, high in zip(min, max)]

new_coord = np.array(np.meshgrid(*bins)).T
coord_norms = norm(new_coord, axis=-1).round().astype(int)
bin_count = np.bincount(coord_norms.flatten())
new_count = bin_count[coord_norms]
```

Can someone explain how I can index a 1-D array (bin_count) using a 2-D array (coord_norms)?
I do understand numpy broadcasting and advanced indexing, but would like to understand what`s going on behind the scenes in this case. Does bin_count first get broadcasted to the same shape as coord_norms?
How does Python assign the values in new_data?

Comment: Concretely, bin_count is of shape (12,) and coord_norms of shape (16, 16)

Comment: This is not Python, but a Numpy ndarray feature. `new_count` gets the same shape as `coord_norms`. Each element at position `i,j` in `new_count` gets the value of `bin_count` at position `coord_norms[i,j]`.

Comment: In other words, there is no broadcasting magic at play. If you have an array `arr`, that you index with an array `b`, naturally the output shape will follow the index shape. If `b` is just a scalar, then the output is a scalar. If `b` is an 1D array, your output will be an 1D array. And so on.

Comment: Alright, so coord_norms[i,j] gets evaluated to say 5. Then this value (5) is used such that new_count[i,j] = bin_count[5] ?

Comment: And what happens if coord_norms[i,j] gets evaluated to say 12, but bin_count has only 5 elements. Does that raise an IndexError?

Comment: Exactly. If `a = np.array([5,6])`, then `a[[[0, 1], [0, 1]]]` (a 2D index) would evaluate to `[[5, 6], [5, 6]]`.